# Raise an event for every child window created by a process - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, process

In my c# application I want a code which will raize an event whenever a process called A has a child window.
I want that the event args will contain the handle of the window.
Can you please post a sample for this question?

Thanks.

Comment: You have +20 non accepted answers ...

Comment: because these answers are not the answer I am looking for. all the answers which are correct - are signed with V.

Comment: That's possible. However, it does not sound good ..

Comment: take look at this link [How to Write a Managed Global Hook for Window Creation and Destruction](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/global_hook_cbt.aspx) i think its what you want